# Prove that $\{x^2+x , x^2-1, x+1\}$ generates vector space of $2^{nd}$ degree polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am quite new to linear algebra and am having some trouble with the abstractness of some it's parts. For example, this task seems quite simple and as if there's no need to do any proving, but to actually prove it using linear algebra axioma can seem tricky.

If the set  $\{x^2+x , x^2-1, x+1\}$  generates vector space of $2^{nd}$ degree polynomials, that would have to mean that the linear span of this set is this vector space i.e. 
$L(\{x^2+x , x^2-1, x+1\}) = P_2[\mathbb{R}]$

This means that for some vector $p$ from $P_2[\mathbb{R}]$, :
$$p=\alpha(x^2+x)+\beta (x^2-1) + \gamma (x+1)$$
$$p=x^2(\alpha +\beta ) + x(\alpha + \gamma)+(\gamma-\beta) $$
Now, the real question here is: In what relation do these coefficient with $x^2$, $x$ and $x^0$  have to be in order for this set to generate this vector space. I believe none of them can be zero in order for this to be true. This is a *required* property, but is it *enough*?

Comment: It suffices to show that you can express each of $x^2$, $x$, and $1$ as linear combinations of $x^2+2$, $x^2-1$, and $x+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i want to see if $x$ can be generated by $\{x^2 + x, x^2 - 1,x+1\}.$ suppose  $$a(x^2 + x)+b(x^2 - 1) + c(x+1) = x$$  is an identity. then we have $$a+b = 0,\\a+c =1,\\-b+c= 0 $$ this system of equations gives $$a = -b, c = b, a+c = 0 $$ therefore is inconsistent. that is $\{x^2 + x, x^2 - 1,x+1\}$  cannot generate $x$ and therefore cannot generate second degree polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

The space of polynomials of $\deg 2$ has dimension 3. So, the polynomials in question will generate the space if they are linearly independent.

Comment: Damn, beat me by 30 seconds!! :)

Comment: Lol. And I'm doing this on my phone. :)

Comment: No fair, you're an university instructor and I am a university student. I should get a head start!!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Write the matrix of vectors in the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$  and use row reduction:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&-1&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&-1&1\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&-1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
The matrix has rank $2$, just as the polynomials. Hence they are *not* a basis of polynomials of degree $\le2$.

Comment: The first row  and the second row  of the first matrix are  wrong.

Comment: ??? The coordinates of the vectors in the new basis are written as `column vectors`.

Comment: Oh,  sorry, I treat them as row vectors. But in any case  the  first determinant equals $0$ , so they are not a basis.

Comment: You're right, there was an error in one of the row operations. I've corredted it.Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

That is wrong becouse  those vectors are linearly depended
$$
1\cdot (x^2+x)+(-1) \cdot (x^2-1)+(-1) \cdot (x+1)=0.
$$

Comment: It didn't say to show that they are a basis -- simply that they generate the space.  So, linear dependence is not a problem.

Comment: no,  it is the problem - they does not generate the space, becouse the dimension of the space is 3 but we have only 2 linearly independed vectors

Comment: Touche. :-)  Absolutely correct.